# nested loops - run day-by-day loop on 3 instruments

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-loops

Hi I am trying to run a loop on 200 days of data, where it shall read 1 day at a time across 3 instruments. So far I can run one day on the 3 instruments before it stops (i use a "break" statement, otherwise it would run one instrument to the end).

```
static public void downloade()
{
    string[] markets = { "CLK15", "HOK15", "GCJ15" };

    for (int i  = 0; i < markets.Length; i++)
    {

        string[] lines;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString
                ("http://ds01.ddfplus.com/historical/queryeod.ashx?username=XX&password=XX&symbol=" + markets[i] + "&maxrecords=200&data=daily");
        lines = downloadString.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        for (int j = 0; j < closePrice.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(datePrice[j].ToShortDateString() + " " + closePrice[j]); 
            break;   
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a specific question or problem?

Comment: Your loop over closePrice is useless.  You setup the loop and then immediately break after the first iteration.  The loop will only ever execute for j == 0, and will never reach j == 1.  Im unsure what your specific question is?

Comment: i need to somehow run a loop for day 1 to day 200 (or closePrice.length), across 3 instruments. So for day 1... get the price for instrument x, y, z.... and then do some calculations... when done i move on to day 2 and obtain prices on x, y, z.... and so forth

Comment: so my question is ... how do I incorporate this?

Comment: Your break-statement is quite confusing. It breaks iteration of the INNER loop, thereby you get only the first day for every instrument. Remove this statement and everything is fine.

Comment: if I remove the "break" then it runs through x to the end... and don't jump to product y and z. Basically i need to compare day 1 price on x, y & z, and then jump to day 2...

Comment: Why do you think it does? I cannot see any reason for this, as I already said: your break only breaks the INNER loop, not the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the loop doing like this and removed the "break" statement.

```
for (int i  = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < markets.Length; j++)
                    {
```